In Kotlin how i change a button color during a specific time?
I'm using Android Studio and I need a button that, when pressed, stays one color for 2 seconds and returns the original color.
import android.graphics.Color


//Object Var
val btt = findViewById<Button>(R.id.BttGameNum)

//Whem clicked change the color
btt.setOnClickListener(){
            if ( btt.text.toString().toInt() == result){
                btt.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
            }
            else{
                btt.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
            }
        }


You can use Handler. Once the button pressed, set the Handler.

You can use coroutine here is a sample. If your doing it in an activity you can use lifecycleScope, if you are doing it inside a fragment you can use viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope
val btt = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)

btt.setOnClickListener {
    if ( btt.text.toString().toInt() == result){
        btt.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
    }
    else{
        btt.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
    }

    lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

        // add a 2 seconds delay
        delay(2000)

        // set to the original color
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            btt.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
        }
    }
}

